# What would be the Visual Basic code to have an Always-Focused form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I know what Always-On-Top is, but that isn't the thing I'm looking for.

By "always-focused" I mean that when I click OUTSIDE the form, it doesn't grey out and become unusable, I want the form to stay in focus, and still fire my KeyDown events when I click out of the screen.

Comment: This is not (easily) possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VBA, are you looking for the "ShowModal" form property?  This will require the form to be closed before things outside the form can be used.  Until it is closed, the form will always be "focused".

For VB.NET, you can use the ShowDialog event, but this will not allow the user to do any work outside the form until it is closed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for VBA to be a tag, I chose it for some reason though.

Comment: Note that this works locally for your application, which is the only sane implementation. The user can still click outside of your app and switch to another one running on the system. It's not clear from the wording of the question which was desired.

Comment: True--I guess we could wire the "Leave" event or create a timer to keep our application on top--but that might get quite annoying for the user.  :)